# How to slightly indent multicolumns / subrows

Tags: tables

I want to make my age subrows/columns slightly indented to the right of the bolded Age row. Any tips?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\hline

\textbf{Characteristics} & \textbf{All participants}  & \textbf{MC using} & \textbf{Non-using} & \textbf{Test Statistic} \\
\   &   & \textbf{participants} & \textbf{participants} & \textbf{(p-value)} \\
\hline


\textbf{Age} (n, \%)    &             &                       &              &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{<25}        &     167        &    58 (34.7)       &  109 (65.3)    &       \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{25-35}      &     570        &    177 (31.1)      &   393 (68.9)   &  $\chi^2$ = 0.00345      \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{>35}        &     306        &    67 (21.9)        &  239 (78.1)    &       \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Have you tried replacing all instances of `\multicolumn{1}{l}` with `\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}`?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I meant slightly indented to the right of my bolded Age row.

Answer (score 6):

You may like the following table format:

[image]

By using `tabularray`, `booktabs` and `siunitx` packages the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \sisetup{input-open-uncertainty =,
             input-close-uncertainty=,
             }

\begin{tblr}{colspec  = {Q[c,mode=math] 
                         c 
                         *{2}{Q[c,si={table-format=3}]@{\;}
                              Q[c,si={table-format={(}2.1{)}}]}
                         c},
             row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries, rowsep=3pt}
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c, mode=text} Characteristics
        & \SetCell[c=5]{c} Participants (n, \%) 
                &      &       &     &        & \SetCell[r=2]{c}
                                          {Test Statistic\\
                                           (p-value)}       \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-6}
        & All   & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{MC using}}}  
                       &       & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{Non-using}}} 
                                     &        &                     \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=1]{c,mode=text, font=\bfseries} Age    
        &       &     &        &     &        &                     \\
<25     & 167   &  58 & (34.7) & 109 & (65.3) &                     \\
25-35   & 570   & 177 & (31.1) & 393 & (68.9) & $\chi^2=0.00345$    \\
>35     & 306   &  67 & (21.9) & 239 & (78.1) &                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where to read more about this option table-format={(}2.1{)} to include the number in parentheses?

Comment: @Diaa, in `siunitx` package documentation, page 42.

Answer (score 3):

With `nicematrix`, `booktabs` and `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\sisetup{input-open-uncertainty =,
         input-close-uncertainty=,
         }
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}cc*{2}{S[table-format=3]@{\;}S[table-format={(}2.1{)}]}c@{}}
\toprule
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,bold]{}
\Block{2-1}{Characteristics}
        & \Block{1-5}{Participants (n, \%)} &&&&& \Block{2-1}{Test Statistic\\ (p-value)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6}
        & All & \Block{1-2}{MC using} && \Block{1-2}{Non-using} \\
\midrule
\bfseries Age \\
$<25$      & 167   &  58 & (34.7) & 109 & (65.3) \\
$25$--$35$ & 570   & 177 & (31.1) & 393 & (68.9) & $\chi^2=0.00345$ \\
$>35$      & 306   &  67 & (21.9) & 239 & (78.1) \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

I guess the following is the intended alignment of the contents in the first column:

[image]

The amount of indentation can be adjusted by alternig the value of `\hspace`. Use `\muticolumn{1}{l}{...}` for all contents in the first column that are not supposed to be indented.

Side note: I did not do any other changes to the table altough I agree with the redesigns (shortened column headers, use of horizontal lines from `booktabs`,  imrpoved alignment of numbers using `siunitx`) already suggested by Zarko and F. Pantigny in their previous anwers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{15pt}}lccccc}
\hline

\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Characteristics}} & \textbf{All participants}  & \textbf{MC using} & \textbf{Non-using} & \textbf{Test Statistic} \\
\   &   & \textbf{participants} & \textbf{participants} & \textbf{(p-value)} \\
\hline


\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Age} (n, \%)}    &             &                       &              &            \\
<25        &     167        &    58 (34.7)       &  109 (65.3)    &       \\
 25-35      &     570        &    177 (31.1)      &   393 (68.9)   &  $\chi^2$ = 0.00345      \\
 >35        &     306        &    67 (21.9)        &  239 (78.1)    &       \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```